# Why isn't php happy with a public method signature being incompatible with the parent private method signature?

Tags: php, inheritance, visibility

The following piece of code

```
<?php

class A {
    private function test($str = null) {
        echo $str;
    }
}

class B extends A {
    public function test() {
        echo 'b';
    }
}

$b = new B();
$b->test();
```

gives

> Warning: Declaration of B::test() should be compatible with A::test($str = NULL) in /in/oCG5c on line 13

Proof [here](https://3v4l.org/oCG5c).

Why is this ? Notice how the parent method is private, notice how this is not a problem for hhvm, and notice how php 7 promotes this to a warning.

UPDATE: to make things a bit clearer, the following piece of code, as expected, [gives no warning](https://3v4l.org/rYiVN) :

```
<?php

class A {
    private function test($str = null) {
        echo $str;
    }
}

class B extends A {
    private function test() {
        echo 'b';
    }
}

$b = new B();
```

If it helps, here is a small reminder of what private means for properties :

```
<?php

class A
{
    private $a;
}

class B extends A
{
    private $a;
}

$b = new B();
var_dump($b);
```

> object(B)#1 (2) { ["a":"B":private]=> NULL ["a":"A":private]=> NULL }

Having two private properties with the same name is just fine. So should it be for methods.

Comment: It's less to do with visibility and more to do with arguments passed (or lack of in your case)

Comment: Method signature isn't the same. You lack `$str = null` in the `B` class.

Comment: I'm unsure what the question is. You ask why you get the warning ,but don't say what you would expect instead.

Comment: @all : I expect no warning at all! The parent method is private, and can't be called from the child class. Why should the signatures be incompatible in that case?

Comment: I updated my question to clarify some things

Comment: @Dale : as you can see, it has everything to do with visibility

Comment: @greg0ire hindsight is a great thing!

Comment: I'll give it to you, this is not an easy question, I hope it is clearer now :)

Comment: I understand your question completely (makes more sense with the update!), I cannot speak on how PHP internally deals with visibility in cases like this, but, from what I can see... it doesn't deal with visibility and just throws a hissy fit regarding the method signature! go figure :)

Comment: The answer from a language level is "because that's how it was designed / implemented". If you want the _why_ it's implemented like this, ask internals.

Comment: I'm asking here first in case there is a reason I might have missed, that would make sense.

Comment: @Dale : oh right, I see what you meant now